# What is the best way to convert a org.joda.time.DateTime to a java.time.OffsetDateTime?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time, datetime-conversion

The following works, but it seems a little clumsy to convert the time to a `long`, and then an `Instant` as well as converting the timezone to a `TimeZone` and then a `ZoneId`. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
java.time.Instant instant = java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(jodaDateTime.getMillis());
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant,
        jodaDateTime.getZone().toTimeZone().toZoneId());
```

Comment: That looks to be the expected complexity of the solution

Comment: It looks fine - if performance is not a concern you could do it via strings: `OffsetDateTime.parse(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().fmt(jodaDateTime), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);` - not sure it's less clumsy though...

Comment: I would suggest you just use one or the other in your code.
Using both joda.time and java-time you can get into complications and confusions in your code. 
The other solution you could do is to use a formatter to output your time from joda to string, then deserialize it using a different JavaTime Formatter.

Answer (score 6):

That seems to be the general way of doing such conversion.

As the classes from both API's are not interoperable with each other (you can't use Joda's `DateTime` with Java Time's `DateTimeFormatter` and so on), the common factor between them seems to be the `long` *epochMilli* value.

So I see no better way than creating a `java.time.Instant` and then converting it to `OffsetDateTime` using the timezone from Joda's object.

Well, I think there's one thing that can be **slightly** improved. This code:

```
jodaDateTime.getZone().toTimeZone().toZoneId()
```

The `toTimeZone()` method creates a `java.util.Timezone` instance, which is used to create a `java.time.ZoneId` via `toZoneId()` method.

You can avoid the creation of this temporary `TimeZone` object by doing:

```
ZoneId.of(jodaDateTime.getZone().getID())
```

This code doesn't create the temporary `TimeZone` object, and creates the `ZoneId` directly. As Joda's [`DateTimeZone` doesn't work with short IDs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) (like `IST` or `PST`), we can assume that the ID will be recognizable by `ZoneId` class (as it also works with long ID names, such as `Europe/London`). It also works if the Joda's `DateTimeZone` ID is an offset (such as `+01:00`).

Not sure if avoiding the creation of one temporary object is cleaner enough, but anyway it's an improvement (a tiny one, but it still is).

So, the final code will be very similar to yours, with only the change proposed above:

```
// java.time.Instant
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(jodaDateTime.getMillis());

// create the OffsetDateTime
OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of(jodaDateTime.getZone().getID()));
```

---

There's another alternative (very similiar, but not sure if cleaner): get the total offset (instead of the timezone) and use it to create a `java.time.ZoneOffset`:

```
long millis = jodaDateTime.getMillis();
// java.time.Instant
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);

// get total offset (joda returns milliseconds, java.time takes seconds)
int offsetSeconds = jodaDateTime.getZone().getOffset(millis) / 1000;
OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(offsetSeconds));
```

---

You can also use the suggestion made by [@assylias' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723232/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-org-joda-time-datetime-to-a-java-time-offsetda#comment66744508_39723232), but I'm not sure if formatting to a `String` and then parsing it to `OffsetDateTime` is cleaner than this (although it also works).